# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable ERROR KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I have this error in Kotlin, says Duplicate Class Found, how can I solve?

```
tty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.MessageSizeEstimator$Handle found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.PendingBytesTracker found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.PendingBytesTracker$1 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.PendingBytesTracker$ChannelOutboundBufferPendingBytesTracker found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.PendingBytesTracker$DefaultChannelPipelinePendingBytesTracker found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.PendingBytesTracker$NoopPendingBytesTracker found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.PendingWriteQueue found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.PendingWriteQueue$1 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.PendingWriteQueue$PendingWrite found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.PendingWriteQueue$PendingWrite$1 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.PreferHeapByteBufAllocator found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.RecvByteBufAllocator found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.RecvByteBufAllocator$DelegatingHandle found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.RecvByteBufAllocator$ExtendedHandle found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.RecvByteBufAllocator$Handle found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.ReflectiveChannelFactory found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.SelectStrategy found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.SelectStrategyFactory found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.ServerChannel found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.SimpleUserEventChannelHandler found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventLoop found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.SucceededChannelFuture found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.ThreadPerChannelEventLoop found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.ThreadPerChannelEventLoop$1 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.ThreadPerChannelEventLoop$2 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.ThreadPerChannelEventLoopGroup found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.ThreadPerChannelEventLoopGroup$1 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.VoidChannelPromise found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.VoidChannelPromise$1 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.WriteBufferWaterMark found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel$1 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel$2 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel$EmbeddedChannelPipeline found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel$EmbeddedUnsafe found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel$EmbeddedUnsafe$1 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel$State found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannelId found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedEventLoop found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedSocketAddress found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroup found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroupException found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroupFuture found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroupFutureListener found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.ChannelMatcher found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.ChannelMatchers found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.ChannelMatchers$1 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.ChannelMatchers$ClassMatcher found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.ChannelMatchers$CompositeMatcher found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.ChannelMatchers$InstanceMatcher found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.ChannelMatchers$InvertMatcher found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.CombinedIterator found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup$1 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroupFuture found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroupFuture$1 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroupFuture$DefaultEntry found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.group.VoidChannelGroupFuture found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.internal.ChannelUtils found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.local.LocalAddress found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.local.LocalChannel found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.local.LocalChannel$1 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.local.LocalChannel$2 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.local.LocalChannel$3 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.local.LocalChannel$4 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.local.LocalChannel$5 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.local.LocalChannel$6 found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
Duplicate class io.netty.channel.local.LocalChannel$LocalUnsafe found in modules netty-transport-4.1.64.Final (io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.64.Final) and openfoodfacts-java-wrapper-0.9.3 (pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3)
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("io.realm.kotlin")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    kotlin("kapt")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.fiicodeapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.fiicodeapp"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.20")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended")

    // Compose dependencies
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.2.0")

    // Coroutines
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3")


    //Dagger and Hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.49")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.49")

    //Realm
    implementation("io.realm.kotlin:library-base:1.11.0")

    // Coil
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.4.0")

    //Json
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.0")

    // Open Food Facts Api Java Wrapper
    implementation("pl.coderion:openfoodfacts-java-wrapper:0.9.3")
}
```